# What's wrong with my dynamically placed Fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I want to rewrite my activities to dialogs, and I want to replace dialogs programmatically. I tried fragments staticaly and it is works fine. When I programmatically call fragment and debug it with breakpoints I don't understand why its lifecycle starts from onCreate() and ends on it... Why from onCreate() and don't from onAttach() like when I call it statically? here is my code, help me plz!!!

base_activity.xml `

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/base_drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout

        android:id="@+id/base_fragment_holder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

`

BaseActivity.java

```
    public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.base_activity);

        DietsFragment dietsFragment = new DietsFragment();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.base_fragment_holder, dietsFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

    }
}
```

DietsFragment.java

```
public class DietsFragment extends Fragment
        implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener,
        View.OnClickListener {
    public FragmentEventListener fragmentEventListener;

    Cursor diets;
    DietAdapter adapter;
    DietHelper helper;
    ListView listView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_diets, container, false);

        listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.act_diets_lv_diets);
        if (listView != null) {
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        }

        FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.act_diets_fab);
        if (floatingActionButton != null)
            floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        setHelper(new DietHelper(getActivity()));
        setDiets(getHelper().getAllTableRecordsCursor());
        setAdapter(new DietAdapter(getActivity(), getDiets()));
        listView.setAdapter(getAdapter());
        fragmentEventListener = (FragmentEventListener) getActivity();
    }

    public void setDiets (Cursor diets) {
        this.diets = diets;
    }

    public void setAdapter (DietAdapter adapter) {
        this.adapter = adapter;
    }

    public void setHelper (DietHelper helper) {
        this.helper = helper;
    }

    public Cursor getDiets() {
        return diets;
    }

    public DietAdapter getAdapter() {
        return adapter;
    }

    public DietHelper getHelper() {
        return helper;
    }
}
```

in DietsFragment and BaseActivity i hide its implementetions of OnClickListener,  OnItemClickListener and FragmentEventListener, cause it works fine when i add fragment in BaseActivity statically from xml with

Answer (score 0):

I've just found my mistake... **I overloaded findViewbyId(int resId) in BaseActivity and that all my problem**, and now i'm asking myself WHY I OVERLOAD THAT METHOD WHAT WAS I WANTED TO DO WITH IT?